# Android studio click not performing

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I am starting to write instrumentation tests for my app using Espresso, however I have come into a problem.

on my test when I try to click on my sign up button

```
onData(withId(R.id.signUpButton)).perform(click());
```

I get the error

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView'.
```

I changed from `onView` to `onData` as when using `onView` I was recieving the error message

`android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: uk.co.vouchercodes.android.beta:id/signUpButton
If the target view is not part of the view hierarchy, you may need to use Espresso.onData to load it from one of the following AdapterViews:android.widget.GridView{5c810ee VFED..C.. ........ 0,0-1080,1376 #7f1001f0 app:id/onboardingMerchantGridView}`

Has anyone experienced similar problems? What is the best way around this problemo?

Thanks 
 *XML*

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/vc_green_5_onboarding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/authScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
            style="@style/PaddedLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/authTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="AUTH TITLE"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_standard"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/signupContentLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_double"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:src="@drawable/name_icon"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameField"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/name"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_half"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:background="@drawable/authorization_edittext"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords|textPersonName"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_double"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:src="@drawable/email_icon"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/emailField"
                    android:layout_width="0px"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_half"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:background="@drawable/authorization_edittext"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/passwordLabel"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_double"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:src="@drawable/password_icon"
                    android:scaleType="fitStart"
                    android:tint="@color/white"/>

            <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwordField"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_half"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                    android:background="@drawable/authorization_edittext"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forgotPasswordText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/signButton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/sign_up"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_standard"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_auth_white_stroke"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/onboarding_or"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_top"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/onboarding_button_height"
                android:text="@string/facebook_connect"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_facebook_background"
                android:paddingLeft="40dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_padlock"
                    android:padding="4dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/facebook_no_post"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="4dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/switchTextView"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/onboarding_privacy_and_terms_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:text="@string/auth_switch_to_signin"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/onboarding_text_size_pin"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/privacyTermsText"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/onboarding_privacy_and_terms_width"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:text="@string/auth_privacy_terms"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_standard"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you should use `onView` and figure out why exactly there is no button present when you run your test

Comment: @bartekLipinski I have done and receiving this error `Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
at least 90 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.`

Comment: Yes, you have to figure out exactly that. When you start your espresso test is this button visible to you?

Comment: is it hidden? maybe scrolled off the screen?

Comment: Nope it is in the centre of the screen my only thought was it could of been the keyboard  covering it so I added `onView(withId(R.id.onboardingParentFrameLayout)).perform(ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard());` but the issue still occurs.

Comment: updated question with XML

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onView method. Your problem is that using wrong id. You defined button named as signButton but you're using the button named as signUpButton therefore you get an error.